# Vue not rendering my data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a component that I get data on create with ajax and I show this in a Template. Basically I have this:

my Vue code:

```
 Vue.component('feedback-table', {
    template: '#grid-template',
    data: function () {
        return {
            chancesOfApproval:[],
        }
    },
    created:function(){
        $.getJSON('/getFeedbackQuestionsAndChances',function(data){
            this.chancesOfApproval = data.chancesOfApproval;
        }.bind(this));
    },


});

new Vue({
    el: '#feedback-wrapper',
});
```

And here is my template:

```
<template id="grid-template">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped">
        <tr v-for="entry in chancesOfApproval">
            <td>@{{ entry.position }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</template>

<div id="feedback-wrapper">
    <feedback-table></feedback-table>
</div>
```

The data is being getted from the jquery because if I do console.log(this.chanceOfApproval) for example, it appears fine in  the console. And I do not get any error in my console, so I have no idea why it does not work.

Comment: Do you have VueJS Dev tools for Chrome ? How are data represented there ?

Comment: Yes I do, and it shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

It behaves as expected here, where I've switched out the `getJSON` for a `setTimeout` doing the same assignment.

```js
Vue.component('feedback-table', {
  template: '#grid-template',
  data: function() {
    return {
      chancesOfApproval: [],
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    /*
    $.getJSON('/getFeedbackQuestionsAndChances', function(data) {
      this.chancesOfApproval = data.chancesOfApproval;
    }.bind(this));
    */
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.chancesOfApproval = [{
        position: 1
      }, {
        position: 2
      }];
    }, 500);
  },


});

new Vue({
  el: '#feedback-wrapper',
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="grid-template">

  <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped">
    <tr v-for="entry in chancesOfApproval">
      <td>@{{ entry.position }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>

<div id="feedback-wrapper">
  <feedback-table></feedback-table>
</div>
```

Comment: All your code only on my html page works fine, but if I put it on different files, it does not work. The weird part is that if I put a var test:'a' and try to render it on my template, it works just fine

Comment: Sounds like there's a problem with the Laravel side putting things together. Not something I have experience with. :(

Answer (score 0):

You are using function.bind(this) to bring `this` from outer scope to the function scope, in your `$http` success handler.

Have you checked if it is not creating any issues? I am not aware of how `bind` is implemented. Maybe it is not allowing Vue to trigger its *[Reactivity System](https://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html)*.

If you see values in console as a plain JSON object, then it is probably wrong. Vue.js modifies object params to getters / setters / observers so that it can bind to the DOM.

Alternatively, why dont you try the arrow function or using a `self` variable, just to see if it solves the issue?

Arrow function (ES6 and above):

```
created:function(){
    $.getJSON('/getFeedbackQuestionsAndChances',data => {
        this.chancesOfApproval = data.chancesOfApproval;
    });
}
```

Or use a local variable:

```
created:function(){
    var self = this;  // self points to this of Vue component
    $.getJSON('/getFeedbackQuestionsAndChances',function(data){
        self.chancesOfApproval = data.chancesOfApproval;
    });
}
```

Another note: instead of `setTimeout()`, you also have the option of `Vue.nextTick()` as follows:

```
Vue.nextTick(function () {
  // DOM updated
})
```

or in your case:

```
this.$nextTick(function () {
  // DOM updated
})
```

Comment: I tried that, and also did not work. But I find out that it is happening when I import this file in another file (import Feedback from "./Feedback";) If I remove this import from the other file, it works just fine. Can not I import files with global Vue components?

Comment: I have not attempted your way of doing - using jQuery.getJSON inside a view component, so I do not know what is going wrong here. Have you tried using `vue-resource`? (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource) That is the official plugin for managing all http requests.

Comment: vue-resource is also very similar to getJSON method, you can look at the example in its github page. You will do as follows: `this.$http.get('/someUrl').then(response => { ... });`

Comment: Yes, I know about vue-resources, the reason of doing with jquery is because I was following a tutorial in laracast